# ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add None to Spark environment

Tags: apache-spark, exception, pyspark, config, java-io

I submit a spark job first like this in a pyspark file

```
    os.system(f'spark-submit --master local --jars ./examples/lib/app.jar app.py')
```

Then in the submitted app.py file, I create a new SparkSession like this:

```
  spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(appName) \
        .config('spark.jars') \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Error message:

```
23/01/17 11:02:52 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.0
23/01/17 11:02:52 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/01/17 11:02:52 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
23/01/17 11:02:52 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/01/17 11:02:52 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: symbolic_test
23/01/17 11:02:52 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
23/01/17 11:02:52 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: annie
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: annie
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(annie); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(annie); groups with modify permissions: Set()
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 42141.
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-e4cc3b01-a6d5-4454-ad2d-4d0f42066479
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 434.4 MiB
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
23/01/17 11:02:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
23/01/17 11:02:53 ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add None to Spark environment
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar /home/annie/exampleApp/example/None not found
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addLocalJarFile$1(SparkContext.scala:1949)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addJar(SparkContext.scala:2004)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$12(SparkContext.scala:507)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$12$adapted(SparkContext.scala:507)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:507)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

when creating spark session through pyspark, I get the following error messages, which only arise when I add .config('spark.jars').

I've set my $SPARK_HOME variable correctly...
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code sample is true you do not assign any value to spark.jars key while creating spark session. Assigning jar path as value may solve the error.

```
SparkSession.builder.appName(appName) \
    .config('config_key', config_value) \
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I also realized this shortly after posting this question. However I am confused as the code I posted above is code I cloned from someone else's repo and they said everything was working fine. I was wondering if I was missing something additional, like spark version conflict or something like that.